# Loop over a list in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, loops

I want to do an operation if each data frame of a list. I want to perform the Kolmogorov–Smirnov (KS) test for one column in each data frame. I am using the code below but it is not working:

```
PDF_mean <- matrix(nrow = length(siteNumber), ncol = 4)
PDF_mean <- data.frame(PDF_mean)
names(PDF_mean) <- c("station","normal","gamma","gev")


listDF <- mget(ls(pattern="DSF_moments_"))
length(listDF)
i <- 1

for (i in length(listDF)) {

PDF_mean$station[i] <- siteNumber[i]
PDF_mean$normal[i] <- ks.test(list[i]$mean,"pnorm")$p.value
PDF_mean$gev[i] <- ks.test(list[i]$mean,"pgev")$p.value
PDF_mean$gamma[i] <- ks.test(list[i]$mean,"gamma")$p.value

}
```

Any help?

Comment: Add a sample of `PDF_mean` in order to reproduce your issue!

Comment: Also, describe how it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

It is not `length(listDF)` instead, it would be `seq_along(listDF)`  or `1:length(listDF)` (however, it is more appropriate with `seq_along`) because `length` is a single value and it is not doing any loop

```
for(i in seq_along(listDF)) {

  PDF_mean$station[i] <- listDF[[i]]$siteNumber
  PDF_mean$normal[i] <- ks.test(listDF[[i]]$mean,"pnorm")$p.value
  PDF_mean$gev[i] <- ks.test(listDF[[i]]$mean,"pgev")$p.value
  PDF_mean$gamma[i] <- ks.test(listDF[[i]]$mean,"gamma")$p.value
 }
```

Comment: using seq_along...I got the following error: Error in list[i] : object of type 'builtin' is not subsettable

Comment: @Sss I guess the `siteNumber` is one of the elements in the `listDF`?

Comment: @Sss can you try the updated code.  Your code had some typos `list` instead of `listDF`